# How can I recover deleted photos and videos from vault app

Tags: samsung, privacy, nqvault

I used vault app to hide some pictures and videos.

I just formatted  my phone after then I re-installed vault and I am unable to find my pictures and videos.

Is there any way to recover my pictures and videos ?

Comment: Did you create backup on cloud?

Comment: Which "vault app" did you use? There are many slightly different ones. Please [edit] your question to add this information.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I think, you can try some data recovery tools. If your lost photos are not rewritten by other data, with a third party tool-Android Recovery Mac, you can easily recover them.

Step 1: Run Android Photo Recovery Mac and Select Files to Recover

Step 2: Connect Your Android Device to Mac and Start Scanning

Step 3: Recover Deleted Pictures from Android on Mac

ANother : Gihosoft free Android data recovery software is quite good at this field, and their software is for free, you can download it and have a try.

Comment: Please link apps / programs mentioned by you in the solution